# Manually trigger an "after UoW" event

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

In the documentation it says that "EntitySav**ed**EventData" will be automatically triggered after the UoW has completed. I want to make a custom event, which only happens after the changes have been saved to the database.
I want to manually trigger the event only in some specific cases. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger after changes have been saved by adding an event handler like [how ABP does it](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/359036f8bc5a63efaa3c2db386bc3760fd31574e/src/Abp/Events/Bus/Entities/EntityChangeEventHelper.cs#L127):

```
_unitOfWorkManager.Current.Completed += (sender, args) =>
{
    // Manually trigger the event only in some specific cases
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the line I was looking for.